# Add water between in a bar chart

Tags: algorithm

Recently came across an interview question in glassdoor-like site and I can't find an optimized solution to solve this problem:

This is nothing like trapping water problem. Please read through the examples.

Given an input array whose each element represents the height of towers, the amount of water will be poured and the index number indicates the pouring water position.The width of every tower is 1. Print the graph after pouring water.

**Notes:**

1. Use `*` to indicate the tower, `w` to represent 1 amount water.
2. The pouring position will never at the peak position.No need to consider the divide water case.

   (A Bonus point if you gave a solution for this case, you may assume that if Pouring N water at peak position, N/2 water goes to left, N/2 water goes to right.)

The definition for a peak: the height of peak position is greater than the both left and right index next to it.)

3. Assume there are 2 extreme high walls sits close to the histogram.
      So if the water amount is over the capacity of the histogram,
      you should indicate the capacity number and keep going. See Example 2.
4. Assume the water would go left first, see Example 1

**Example 1:**

```
int[] heights = {4,2,1,2,3,2,1,0,4,2,1}
It look like:

*       *
*   *   **
** ***  **
******* ***
+++++++++++  <- there'll always be a base layer
42123210431
Assume given this heights array, water amout 3, position 2:
```

Print:

```
*       *
*ww *   **
**w***  **
******* ***
+++++++++++
```

**Example 2:**

```
int[] heights = {4,2,1,2,3,2,1,0,4,2,1}, water amout 32, position 2
```

Print:

```
capacity:21

wwwwwwwwwww
*wwwwwww*ww
*www*www**w
**w***ww**w
*******w***
+++++++++++
```

At first I though it's like [the trapping water problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/trapping-rain-water/#/description) but I was wrong. Does anyone have an algorithm to solve this problem?

An explanation or comments in the code would be welcomed.

**Note:**

The trapping water problem is asked for the capacity, but this question introduced two variables: water amount and the pouring index. Besides, the water has the flowing preference. So it not like trapping water problem.

Comment: If the pouring location were 3, would you want the water to go left, right (deepest valley and biggest capacity), or random?

Comment: @m69 left first. if the left part is full/unable to add water, go right.

Comment: Seems quite straightforward then. Make a 2D grid, start every drop at the top, go down, if that's not possible go left, if that's not possible go right, repeat until you get stuck, repeat for every drop. (Come to think of it, you may have to go right through the top layer of drops to see if there's any more space on that layer, and then backtrack if there isn't. Hm, it's not so simple after all :-) )

Comment: @m69. Yes. It's not that simple after all.  Theoretically, there will be a linear time solution. Comparing to that famous trapping rain problem, this case needs to print the whole picture, and it's hard since there are 2 cases: under capacity and over capacity.

Comment: @Ken White. Do you still think it's a homework problem? or a duplicated trapped rain problem?

Comment: @KK25 Comments saying thanks are not allowed according to the rules, that's why it was removed, but you can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark if one satisfies you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a Python solution to this question. However, I'm not familiar with Python so I quote the code here. Hopefully, someone knows Python could help.

Code by [@z026](http://www.1point3acres.com/bbs/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=220456&page=1#pid2733305)

```
def pour_water(terrains, location, water):
print 'location', location 
print 'len terrains', len(terrains)
waters = [0] * len(terrains)
while water > 0: 
    left = location - 1
    while left >= 0:
        if terrains[left] + waters[left] > terrains[left + 1] + waters[left + 1]:
            break
        left -= 1

    if terrains[left + 1] + waters[left + 1] < terrains[location] + waters[location]:
        location_to_pour = left + 1
        print 'set by left', location_to_pour 
    else: 
        right = location + 1
        while right < len(terrains):
            if terrains[right] + waters[right] > terrains[right - 1] + waters[right - 1]:
                print 'break, right: {}, right - 1:{}'.format(right, right - 1) 
                break
            right += 1 

        if terrains[right - 1] + waters[right - 1] < terrains[location] + waters[right - 1]:
            location_to_pour = right - 1
            print 'set by right', location_to_pour
        else:
            location_to_pour = location 
            print 'set to location', location_to_pour

    waters[location_to_pour] += 1 

    print location_to_pour
    water -= 1

max_height = max(terrains)

for height in xrange(max_height, -1, -1):
    for i in xrange(len(terrains)):
        if terrains + waters < height:
            print ' ',
        elif terrains < height <= terrains + waters:
            print 'w',
        else:
            print '+',
    print ''
```

Comment: It's more or less the same as my code, except that they separate the water height from the terrain height, I cumulated them so I can get rid of a lot of additions. If you subtract the terrain height from my water height, then you get what they have here as water height.

Comment: @maraca yes. I tried your code. Perfectly solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to generate and print out the array anyway, I'd probably opt for a recursive approach keeping to the `O(rows*columns)` complexity. Note each cell can be "visited" at most twice.

**On a high level:** first recurse down, then left, then right, then fill the current cell.

However, this runs into a little problem: (assuming this is a problem)

```
*w    *                *     *
**ww* *   instead of   **ww*w*
```

This can be fixed by updating the algorithm to go left and right first to fill cells *below* the current row, then to go both left and right *again* to fill the current row. Let's say `state = v` means we came from above, `state = h1` means it's the first horizontal pass, `state = h2` means it's the second horizontal pass.

You might be able to avoid this repeated visiting of cells by using a stack, but it's more complex.

**Pseudo-code:**

```java
array[][] // populated with towers, as shown in the question
visited[][] // starts with all false
// call at the position you're inserting water (at the very top)
define fill(x, y, state):
   if x or y out of bounds
          or array[x][y] == '*'
          or waterCount == 0
      return

   visited = true

   // we came from above
   if state == v
      fill(x, y+1, v) // down
      fill(x-1, y, h1) // left , 1st pass
      fill(x+1, y, h1) // right, 1st pass
      fill(x-1, y, h2) // left , 2nd pass
      fill(x+1, y, h2) // right, 2nd pass

   // this is a 1st horizontal pass
   if state == h1
      fill(x, y+1, v) // down
      fill(x-1, y, h1) // left , 1st pass
      fill(x+1, y, h1) // right, 1st pass
      visited = false // need to revisit cell later
      return // skip filling the current cell

   // this is a 2nd horizontal pass
   if state == h2
      fill(x-1, y, h2) // left , 2nd pass
      fill(x+1, y, h2) // right, 2nd pass

   // fill current cell
   if waterCount > 0
      array[x][y] = 'w'
      waterCount--
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array `height` with the height of the terrain in each column, so I would create a copy of this array (let's call it `w` for water) to indicate how high the water is in each column. Like this you also get rid of the problem not knowing how many rows to initialize when transforming into a grid and you can skip that step entirely.

The algorithm in Java code would look something like this:

```java
public int[] getWaterHeight(int index, int drops, int[] heights) {
    int[] w = Arrays.copyOf(heights);
    for (; drops > 0; drops--) {
        int idx = index;
        // go left first
        while (idx > 0 && w[idx - 1] <= w[idx])
            idx--;
        // go right
        for (;;) {
            int t = idx + 1;
            while (t < w.length && w[t] == w[idx])
                t++;
            if (t >= w.length || w[t] >= w[idx]) {
                w[idx]++;
                break;
            } else { // we can go down to the right side here
                idx = t;
            }
        }
    }
    return w;
}
```

Even though there are many loops, the complexity is only O(drops * columns). If you expect huge amount of drops then it could be wise to count the number of empty spaces in regard to the highest terrain point O(columns), then if the number of drops exceeds the free spaces, the calculation of the column heights becomes trivial O(1), however setting them all still takes O(columns).

Comment: Seems your algorithm can't handle the example 2 case. And I don't quite get it why you return an array after the water dropped, in that case, it's hard to print.  Could you please explain?

Comment: Example case 2 is no problem. To print you have to get the max(max(terrain), max(water)) to know how many rows you need. Because you print it top down it's a little complicated. Field (row, col) is empty if the total rows - row is smaller than the water height at col, otherwise it is water if the total rows - row is bigger than terrain height at col, else it is terrain.

Comment: max(water) is actually enough to get the number of rows, forgot it's cumulated.

Comment: Tried to print top down but it's complicated. However, I could print vertically.(like rotate the after-poured histogram 90 degree)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the 2D grid from bottom to top, create a node for every horizontal run of connected cells, and then string these nodes together into a linked list that represents the order in which the cells are filled.
[image]
After row one, you have one horizontal run, with a volume of 1:

```
1(1)
```

In row two, you find three runs, one of which is connected to node 1:

```
1(1)->2(1)    3(1)    4(1)
```

In row three, you find three runs, one of which connects runs 2 and 3; run 3 is closest to the column where the water is added, so it comes first:

```
3(1)->1(1)->2(1)->5(3)    6(1)    4(1)->7(1)
```

In row four you find two runs, one of which connects runs 6 and 7; run 6 is closest to the column where the water is added, so it comes first:

```
3(1)->1(1)->2(1)->5(3)->8(4)    6(1)->4(1)->7(1)->9(3)
```

In row five you find a run which connects runs 8 and 9; they are on opposite sides of the column where the water is added, so the run on the left goes first:

```
3(1)->1(1)->2(1)->5(3)->8(4)->6(1)->4(1)->7(1)->9(3)->A(8)
```

Run A combines all the columns, so it becomes the last node and is given infinite volume; any excess drops will simply be stacked up:

```
3(1)->1(1)->2(1)->5(3)->8(4)->6(1)->4(1)->7(1)->9(3)->A(infinite)
```

then we fill the runs in the order in which they are listed, until we run out of drops.
[image]

Comment: This is obviously a general approach but not a 20-minute coding solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thats my 20 minutes solution. Each drop is telling the client where it will stay, so the difficult task is done.(*Copy-Paste in your IDE*) Only the printing have to be done now, but the drops are taking their position. Take a look:

```
class Test2{
  private static int[] heights = {3,4,4,4,3,2,1,0,4,2,1};
  public static void main(String args[]){
  int wAmount = 10;
  int position = 2;
  for(int i=0; i<wAmount; i++){
    System.out.println(i+"#drop");
    aDropLeft(position);
  }
}

private static void aDropLeft(int position){
  getHight(position);
  int canFallTo = getFallPositionLeft(position);
  if(canFallTo==-1){canFallTo = getFallPositionRight(position);}
  if(canFallTo==-1){
    stayThere(position);
    return;
  }
  aDropLeft(canFallTo);
}

private static void stayThere(int position) {
  System.out.print("Staying at: ");log(position);
  heights[position]++;
}

//the position or -1 if it cant fall
private static int getFallPositionLeft(int position) {
  int tempHeight = getHight(position);
  int tempPosition = position;
  //check left , if no, then check right
  while(tempPosition>0){
    if(tempHeight>getHight(tempPosition-1)){
      return tempPosition-1;
    }else tempPosition--;
  }
  return -1;
}

private static int getFallPositionRight(int position) {
  int tempHeight = getHight(position);
  int tempPosition = position;
  while(tempPosition<heights.length-1){
    if(tempHeight>getHight(tempPosition+1)){
      return tempPosition+1;
    }else if(tempHeight<getHight(tempPosition+1)){
      return -1;
    }else tempPosition++;
  }
  return -1;
}   
private static int getHight(int position) {
return heights[position];
}


private static void log(int position) {
System.out.println("I am at position: " + position + " height: " + getHight(position));
}
}
```

Of course the code can be optimized, but thats my straightforward solution

Comment: A small bug. Your first water drop always goes to position 0.(I tried test case: your heights array, water 10 and water 20, position:2) Although your output is good, it would better if you print a graph instead of logs.

Comment: how is it going to position 0?

Comment: i just tested it even the first drop is going to the expected position

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[0,1,0,2,1,0,1,3,2,1,2,1]

def findwater(l):
    w=0
    for i in range(0,len(l)-1):
        if i==0:
            pass
        else:
            num = min(max(l[:i]),max(l[i:]))-l[i]
            if num>0:
                w+=num
    return w
```

Answer (score 0):

```
col_names=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13] #for visualization
bars=[4,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,5,0,3,0,1]

pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(col_names,bars)),index=range(1)).plot(kind='bar')   # Plotting bars

def measure_water(l):
    water=0
    for i in range(len(l)-1):   # iterate over bars (list)
        if i==0:                # case to avoid max(:i) situation in case no item on left
            pass
        else:
            vol_at_curr_bar=min(max(l[:i]),max(l[i:]))-l[i]   #select min of max heighted bar on both side and minus current height
            if vol_at_curr_bar>0:   # case to aviod any negative sum
                water+=vol_at_curr_bar
    return water

measure_water(bars)
```