# Floodfill up to the rim but no longer

Tags: algorithm, flood-fill

I need an algorithm that fills a domain up to the rim, and returns the pixel(s) where the flood were to escape. You can think of it as filling a lake with water, and finding its sink.

```
      x
  +--->
  |
  |
y v
```

## Input:

**Pixel values:**

```
3 3 3 3 3
3 3 2 2 3
3 1 1 1 3
3 1 1 1 3
3 1 1 1 3
3 2 3 2 3
2 1 1 2 2
```

**Start location:** (x = 2, y = 3)

## Expected output:

**Pixel values:**

```
3 3 3 3 3
3 3 2 2 3
3 2 2 2 3
3 2 2 2 3
3 2 2 2 3
3 2 3 2 3
2 1 1 2 2
```

**Locations:** (x = 1, y = 5), (x = 3, y = 5)

The tricky part is how to find the highest value that can be used (in this case 2) without overfill to occur. Notice that using `<` as stopping condition will not work, since it will then continue over any boundary (in this case it would spill over the threes, not just the lowest boundary. The traditional floodfill uses `==`, but that would not work either, since it is not known a priori what to compare against.

The question is similar to [Total water capacity in a 2D array, which represents a topographical map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888906/total-water-capacity-in-a-2d-array-which-represents-a-topographical-map?rq=1), but the accepted answer requires that the boundary of the domain is already known, but in my case, I need to also find the boundary.

Comment: Hi, can you add what you have tried?

Comment: @Reg I know how to implement floodfill, but need some help in modifying it to work for this problem. Sure, I could differentiate the input image to try to find edges, but that method only works for ideal cases (without too much noise).

Comment: Are diagonal moves possible (is that how you got x=1,y=5)?

Comment: @ggorlen 2 is the lowest value greater than 1, Thus, it will spill over at that point. From that point and on the next local minimum, I will continue to march on following steepest descent. When steepest descent get stuck, create a lake. But I need to figure out how to create that lake.

Comment: Can you add the coordinate system you're using for the example? Neither the Cartesian nor 2-D, zero-indexed array coordinates seem to match your output.